# What model incorporates air resistance into an otherwise parabolic trajectory?

Tags: projectile, geometry, differential-equations

Let's suppose we had a projectile of mass $m$, initial angle $\theta$ launched with an initial velocity $x'$ and $y'$ in a 2D coordinate plane.

If you'd like to approximate this trajectory ignoring air resistance, you'd end up with quadratic equations, but let's say instead you did intend to incorporate air resistance into your model.

Is there a system of linear differential equations which approximates the projectile's motion in both the $x$ and $y$ coordinate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know exactly how to ask what I'm looking for. I know that if you incorporate linear wind resistance into your model, a central difference is the appearance of exponential functions. That appearance of the exponential function likely cooresponds to a linear ODE.